# How to prevent "str\0ing" from escaping during copy function in C?

Tags: c, string, escaping, terminator

Let's say I have:

```
 char a[] = "str\0ing"
```

and I want to copy this string into another character array,

```
char b[].
```

However, my function seems to be hitting the terminator sequence (or at least the forward slash) and stopping, such that the only thing that is copied into b[] is "str".  What exactly is happening here, and how might I get around this?

I'm running a simple For loop with the format b[i] == a[i]. Thanks.

Edit: I apologize for being very unclear, this is my first post here.
This is my current code:

```
int copyStringN(char * in, char * out, int n) {
  int i;
  if (!in || !out) return -1;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    *out++ = *in++;
  }
  *out= '\0';
  return 0;
}

int main() {
#define N 8
  char a[] = "th\0ing";
  char b[N];
  int err;
  err = copyStringN(a, b, N);
  assert (!err);
  printf("%s\n", b);
  return 0;
}
```

The restriction is that it MUST be able to print "\0" if it is present, so I cannot simply add another backslash in the string. I have to somehow code my function to interpret this character sequence as explicit characters and not a terminator.

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: Then tell your function not to consider `\0` to be a terminator.

Comment: You gotta know the array length. Character arrays are NOT strings (in general, that is, as your example shows.)

Comment: Show us what you've tried.  We can't be of much help if you don't show us what is not working.

Comment: my crystal ball says you're looping on `strlen`, which simply counts until it sees a `'\0'`, so `strlen(a) == 3`. Just use [`memcpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) instead, but note that you'll need to manage the length of the arrays yourself. It's a fundamental error to say you have a string with a `NUL` terminator in the middle. What you have in `a` is an array of characters, and one of those characters happens to be 0. You don't have a string. Don't use string functions on arbitrary binary data.

Comment: It's not even clear if the OP wants a zero byte in the array, or two characters `'\'` and `'0'`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why / where do you need such a "string"?

Comment: I have edited above, I apologize and thank you.

Comment: Okay, now that we see what you're doing and what you've tried, we may get somewhere.  It looks to me like the problem is not that `'\0'` is cancelling while copying, but rather that it tells `printf` that it is the end of the string.  I believe the solution would be, during your copy phase to, when you come across the character `'\0'`, insert `'\\'` followed by `'0'`.  This will result in your output having one extra character in it per `'\0'` it comes across, so keep this in mind for both the size of the output and the counter keeping track of where in the output you are copying to next.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", b);` means "Display each character in `b` until you hit a `\0`. Then stop.". So even if everything is copied, it is not displayed.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted the `\0` to be treated as the `NUL` character (`\0`) itself and not as `\` and `0`, you could use `memcpy()` like

```
char b[sizeof(a)];
memcpy(b, a, sizeof(a));
```

This would copy `sizeof(a)` bytes of `a` to `b`.

Read about `memcpy()` [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm).

As [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) pointed out, this won't work if you have `a` passed as a parameter to a function like

```
void fn(char b[], char a[]);
...
...
fn(b, a);
```

as `sizeof(a)` would give the size of a pointer variable only which is the same for all pointers and regardless of the size of `a`. This is because when passing an array to a function, the address of the array is a passed and the `a` in the function is actually a pointer.

This is so even if the function was like

```
int fn(char b[], char *a);
```

or even

```
int fn(char b[], char a[10]);
```

So if you are passing `a` to a function, be sure to pass its size as well like

```
void fn(char b[], char a[], size_t len)
{
    memcpy(b, a, len);
}
...
...
...
size_t l=sizeof(a);
fn(a, l);
```

Comment: One caveat here: this only works in a scope where the original, array declaration of `a` is visible.  It will break if moved to a function with `a` passed as a parameter.

Comment: I've edited my post to include what I shamelessly left out, I apologize. Thanks.

Comment: `\0` *is* a NUL character. It is *not* two characters, ever. (Unless you escape the backslash itself.)

Answer (score 0):

To get output that *looks* like "str\0ing", escape the NULL character with an extra `\`:

```
int main(void) 
{
    char a[] = "str\\0ing";
    int len = strlen(a);
    char b[len+1];
    for(int i=0;i<len+1;i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
    printf("%s\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Well, that supposes that the OP wants the array to contain the two-character sequence `'\\'`, `'0'` rather than a null character.  He might indeed want that, but whether he does or not is unclear to me.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - not totally clear here either, making a best guess and throwing out an attempt to address the concern.  At the very least, I expect OP to let me know if I have missed the intent.  Thanks.

Comment: I've edited above.  I apologize for the lack of info, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it with a simple for-loop:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a[] = "str\0ing";
    int length = sizeof a / sizeof(char);
    char b[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
    assert(b[0] == 's');
    assert(b[1] == 't');
    assert(b[2] == 'r');
    assert(b[3] == '\0');
    assert(b[4] == 'i');
    assert(b[5] == 'n');
    assert(b[6] == 'g');
    printf("It works\n");
}
```

There are other ways, of course, but you said you were using a for loop, so this is probably closest to what you have already tried.

The idea here is that `a` is not a string. It is a character array. Strings in C are sequences of bytes terminated with a zero-byte. If you want to have a zero-byte inside your string, it is not a string. It is a character array. So the code above copies characters from array `a` to array `b`.

Note the importance of allocating `b` with enough space.

**EDIT**

Okay now that you added on to your question, we can see that you do know how to copy. But your problem is that you expect `printf` to display a string with a zero byte in it. It won't. Not if you just give it the pointer to the beginning of the string.

If you want to print a "string" with a zero-byte in it, the only way to do this is to wrap both the character data and its length into an object and print that with a special printing function.

Or, if you can, just move to C++, which doesn't have trouble at all:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::string s("str\0ing", 7);
  std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

It runs so nice:

```
$ g++ t.cpp && ./a.out
string
```

Tada!

Comment: Updated the answer. If you can't move to C++, then the idea of bundling character data with its length into a struct needs to be the way to go. Though give C++ a try if you can.